# Compare parking meter transactions with historical data

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've got realtime data from parking meters and would like to compare the parking meters current status with historical data. My data contains parking tickets with datetime_start for when they are bought and datetime_stop for when they aren't useful anymore.

This SQL actual works, but are VERY slow. I guess I somehow run through all the data to many times or some other things could be optimised:

```
(SELECT "parking_meter_id", SUM(CASE WHEN Now() BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < ( 
SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '1 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '2 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '3 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '4 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '5 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '6 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '7 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '8 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
/ 8) AS available 
FROM "parking_meter_transactions" 
WHERE 
Now() BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" OR 
Now() - interval '1 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" OR 
Now() - interval '2 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" OR 
Now() - interval '3 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" OR 
Now() - interval '4 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" OR 
Now() - interval '5 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" OR 
Now() - interval '6 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" OR 
Now() - interval '7 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" OR 
Now() - interval '8 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" 
GROUP BY "parking_meter_id") AS transactions
```

The basic idea is to count the amount of tickets which are "legal" as of now(), and compare it with the amounts for the last 8 weeks on the same time of day. This could give a statistic idea of if there should be an available parking spot.

Comment: Why does the WHERE clause cover 16 weeks instead of 8?

Comment: You have datetime_start and datetime_stop all within double-quotes (vs single).  It might be better to show a sample of your data by editing your original question... and use spaces vs tabs for alignment readability.

Comment: @DRapp: Identifiers like column names take either double quotes or no quotes at all. They don't take single quotes.

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE? And fix your where-condition first, it's horrible and probably one of the reasons for bad performance.

Comment: The interval 2 months was wrong, it was from my test on not realtime data. Removed in the code example above.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest build a covering index for your query based on

```
( datetime_start, datetime_stop, parking_meter_id )
```

This way, the database should not have to go to the raw data pages to complete the query.

Also, Adjust your WHERE clause to be very simple as a single date compare range.  In your SUM(case) blocks, yes, you need to differentiate between which week it is applicable, but your WHERE clause could be simplified down to something like

```
WHERE datetime_start > Now() - interval '2 months'
```

Think about it... your "NOW()" call is whatever it is... For grins, just suppose Jan 13 @ 12:00AM.  Because all your WHERE clauses are "OR" together

```
Now - 2 months = Week of Nov 13
Now - 2 months - 1 week = Week of Nov 20
Now - 2 months - 2 weeks = Week of Nov 27
...
Now - 2 months - 8 weeks = Brings us back to Now...
```

So your NET time period is anything where the start date/time is greater than 2 months ago.

That said, and an index as suggested should significantly improve performance.  Look at the complexity of your WHERE clause that it has to keep computing the dates - respective intervals.  Since it can't utilize the index as efficiently, it is probably choking on that.

Having the meter ID in the index will help your GROUP BY clause optimization.

FEEDBACK per comment.

All of your dates are wrapped around at FARTHEST, now() - 2 months.  Don't consider anything prior to that... but now I am seeing you extra WHERE clauses how you only want tickets for the SPECIFIC "NOW()" in time on a per week basis for the 8 weeks.  So the where clause is still validd on just the single condition.

Let the engine blow through all the records from that date/time forward without complex WHERE conditions being applied.  Just remember, your COLUMN SELECTION via SUM( CASE/WHEN ) will only count based on those "Legel" within the time period in question.

SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '1 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN Now() - interval '2 week' BETWEEN "datetime_start" AND "datetime_stop" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +

So, if you are looking for something such as 2:53 in the afternoon, and you have a qualifying WHERE clause record of Jan 2nd at datetime_start 7:59pm, it will fail all the CASE/WHEN instances and NONE of the result columns will have the 1 added to them thus ignoring them.

So, even if there are 10k records from the past 2 months, plow through them fast via the index.  Your case/when will qualify to only count those that are specific to the 2:53 (ex:) time period you are looking for and may only come up with a count of 314 entries across all the week periods.  Such as

```
   Wed, Jan 14 @ 2:53
   Wed, Jan  7 @ 2:53
   Wed, Dec 31 @ 2:53
   Wed, Dec 24 @ 2:53
   Wed, Dec 17 @ 2:53
   Wed, Dec 10 @ 2:53
   Wed, Dec 3 @ 2:53
   Wed, Nov 26 @ 2:53
   Wed, Nov 19 @ 2:53
```

Comment: I will try and edit my where clause tomorrow and return with answer. The reason for my first choice was to only select the ones being used. When selecting ALL records within the last 2 months I also get records between the desired comparisons. Make sense? But perhaps it makes it more complicated and slower than faster.

Comment: I already have index on (datetime_start, datetime_stop) and index on (parking_meter_id)

Comment: @Henrik, I understand your separate index, but having as a single prevents the need of the engine of knowing which to use.  The one by dates AND the parking meter ID can resolve the ENTIRE query without going to the raw data.

Comment: I'm still uncertain with the WHERE statement, as I'm not interested in selecting ALL the records from the last 2 months, but only the ones where records are "legal" within specific dates within the last 2 months.

Comment: @user809829, revised answer... does this help clarify your "legal" qualified records and confirmation of what you are trying to extract from the data?

Comment: A "legal" record in my example would be a parking transaction where start and stop are in between Now(), not only having start before Now().

Comment: @user809829, don't you mean the NOW is between start and stop.  And if so, then how long a period would a start be before a NOW instance in worst-case scenario... 2 hrs, 24 hrs?  If so, just adjust your WHERE clause to NOW - 57 days (8 weeks + 1 day).  Your SUM( CASE ) will still only count those that are legal.  At least it only has to do the case comparison 8 times instead of 16 times (8 for sum, 8 for where).  Simplifying WHERE clause will be optimized with indexes.

Comment: That is correct. I've changed my WHERE clause to only make one comparison.

Comment: @user809829, so did this help the performance of your query by not having 8 where clause tests that were not being optimized by an index on the start time period?  And if so, how much of an improvement to consider this question resolved.